# Laravel, passed php variable to JS function showing as Key not Value

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm currently passing a laravel object's ID through a href click to a JS function

```
<a onclick="getDetails('{{$details->id}}')"</a>
```

And this works to some degree, because my console.log shows id 28 as it should. However, when sending the data in my ajax call my header shows `28:` so it's sending the value as the key with a null value, which means my return is null.

How can I properly change this so that this correct value gets sent in my ajax call as `ID:28`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getDetails(detailID) {
   console.log(detailID);
   $.ajax({
   url: "/details",
   data: detailID,
   _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
   type: "POST",
   success: function (data) {
   console.log(data);
   },
  });
  };
</script>
```

Comment: @TimLewis sorry, typo. just fixed it

Comment: No problem (guessed as much). Next issue, shouldn't `data` be an `object`? like `data: {detailID: detailID},`?

Comment: I believe that's correct, let me see if that's the issue

Comment: That was it! I don't know what I was thinking, but thank you! If you want to make an answer I'll accept it promptly

Comment: Sure thing :) Gimme a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending data via `$.ajax()`, your `data` attribute needs to be a valid object (or similar):

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "/details",
  data: { detailID: detailID },
  _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
  type: "POST",
  success: function (data) {
     console.log(data);
  },
  ...
});
```

There are other valid ways of specifying valid data, but `data: detailID` on its own is not one of them. Also, if you want this accessible as `ID` in Laravel (as initially suggested), simply change to:

```
data: { ID: detailID }
```